# Magento 2: Update order status using rest API

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

Guys I want to update order status using API. I am using this api to change the order status but it's not working:

http://dev-jawed.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders

```
{
"status" : "Out-for-delivery",
"entity" : 1,
"items": {
        "order_id" : 1
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

I think a better answer is to use the following api entry point

> ("/rest/V1/orders/{orderId}/comments", Method.POST);

pass the StatusHistory object in the post body, setting the appropriate fields to update the order status.

```
{
  "statusHistory": {
    "comment": "string",
    "createdAt": "string",
    "entityId": 0,
    "entityName": "string",
    "isCustomerNotified": 0,
    "isVisibleOnFront": 0,
    "parentId": 0, <-- This is the Order ID
    "status": "string",
    "extensionAttributes": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: not all of the fields are required, you can read which ones are required in the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/salesOrderManagementV1AddCommentPost)

Comment: When i am using this api order state is not changing can plz advise

Comment: As @Sebastian said above, but new link here: https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.7-admin/tag/ordersidcomments#operation/salesOrderManagementV1AddCommentPost

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the swagger api documents (either on your local machine at /swagger or at the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/)). You should find the API `V1/orders`. If you are using your local version you will also have the button to try to calls direct from swagger which is nice for debugging. From looking through the documents you should be able to post something like the following to the api.

```
{
  "entity": {
    "entity_id": 0,
    "status": "string"
  }
}
```

Remember to replace the entity_id with the correct order id and the status with the status you would like to change to.

Comment: This will create problems with increment_id (as experienced in Magento 2.2) - order's increment id will be changed (from scope 1 1000000005, to scope 0 (admin) 000000008).

Comment: @David Manners, is there any pattern that we can update staus more than one order in a single API call?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

**PUT /V1/orders/create**

```
'entity' => [
                'entity_id'=> 1,
                'increment_id' => '000000001',
                'status'=> 'processing',
]
```

You currently (v 2.1.*) get the same result with calls:

**PUT /V1/orders/create**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/24f2f071267f9e5ba0d5428b75fcbc76e6ef5b55/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/webapi.xml#L64

**POST /V1/orders**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/24f2f071267f9e5ba0d5428b75fcbc76e6ef5b55/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/webapi.xml#L256

Comment: Is there any pattern that we can update staus more than one order in a single API call?