# Update order status via API

Tags: rest-api, order-status, magento2.3.3

I need to build module that should update the order status via API with tracking number , qty shipped etc.. I have the basic API module but I am stuck with how to update the data

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Check link for reference.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170031/magento-2-update-order-status-using-rest-api

Comment: @KirtiNariya Yes, I see this but i need help how to update the data to Magento backed