# Magento2 update email address vis rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, graphql

Magento2 update Email Address using Rest API. How can I update email address of login customer via Rest API or Graphl

Comment: Can you check this answer.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170031/magento-2-update-order-status-using-rest-api

Comment: Hi,

Please check the below url to add or update the customer information
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154363/how-to-create-update-customer-information-using-rest-api

Comment: do you want to do this into specific location  or what?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by using

rest/V1/customers/me